# How can I declare a function from within a function in Delphi/FreePascal without nesting them?

Tags: function, delphi, scope, pascal

I would like to do something like this:
(I want to conserve the functions public so I can access them from other procedures/functions).
The functions are on the same form (frmSequenciador) - I didn't post it for it is huge in its integrity..

```
function geradorDeVetores():TIntArray;
var
  contador: Integer;
  vetor: array [1..numMax] of integer;
begin
Randomize;
for contador:=1 to numMax do
    begin
      if contador = 1 then
      vetor[contador]=float_round_down(Random*10);
      else vetor[contador]:= ***frmSequenciador.evitaRepeticao(contador, vetor)***;
    end;
end;

function evitaRepeticao(pos: integer; vetor:TIntArray):integer;
var
  numigual: boolean;
  temporario, cont: integer;
begin
     numigual:=true;
     temporario:= float_round_down(Random*10);
     for cont:=1 to pos-1 do
          if temporario <> vetor[cont] numigual:=false else numigual:=true;
     if numigual=false then evitaRepeticao():=temporario else evitaRepeticao():=***frmSequenciador.evitaRepeticao(pos, vetor)***;
end;
```

Comment: I cannot understand this. A nested local function can only be called from its containing function.

Comment: So, there's no way to do like in javascript where a function can call a outside function? Btw, both functions are not nested, they are just in the same form.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to do either. Your call to this function has `frmSequenciador` which means this function is inside of some form object, however the actual function is not. Neither of them are "inside a form".

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't add the whole code for there are about 100 lines of it. They are inside frmSequenciador.

Comment: You can export an anon method. If your compiler supports it. Code not in English doesn't help us. Sorry.

Comment: If the function doesn't belong to the form class then you have to declare it before you use it (or include a forward declaration).  From the function definition it looks like it does not belong to your form, otherwise it would be declared as `function frmSequenciador.evitaRepeticao(...etc` - belonging to the same ***unit*** does not make the function part of the form.

Comment: If they're both methods of `frmSequenciador`, you don't reference the form at all. Just remove the `frmSequenciador.` from both code lines that include it.

Comment: They still do not appear to be a part of your form. I don't see anything nested here.

Comment: I think you're confusing terminology. You say the functions are on the form, but I think you mean in the **unit** that contains the form. For them to be on the form they would have to be declared as `function TSequenciadorForm.evitaRepeticao(pos: integer; vetor:TIntArray): integer;` (or similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple matter of removing the frmSequenciador prefix of the functions as Ken White stated.

What I wanted to know is: if two functions are inside the same form unit (thx Jerry), do we need a prefix to call each other?
It seems not. Thanks all!

Comment: I think you're mistaken. I'm pretty sure those two functions are not a part of any form at all. Part of the form's unit, yes. But not the actual form. Otherwise, the functions would be prefixed with the form type, for example `procedure TfrmSequenciador.evitaRepeticao( ... );`

Comment: @Jerry: Then the solution is still to remove the form reference from the code lines, so it's a win/win.

Comment: To clarify: You should **never** use `frmSequenciador.` from inside a form's methods. If you need to reference the form, use `Self.` instead. Using the `frm.` ties it to a particular instance of the form, while `Self` applies to any and all instances of the form. Using `Form1` might work if you're auto-creating the form, but the minute you create it yourself like `var MyForm: TForm1; begin MyForm := TForm1.Create(nil); MyForm.DoSomething` and `TForm1.DoSomething` uses `Form1.Memo1.Add('Some text');`, you have an access violation.

Comment: @Ken I'm just trying to teach OP a thing or two they didn't think of before to avoid future confusion.

Comment: @Jerry: Then the comment should be made to the question. The answer isn't mistaken; removing the `frmSequenciador.` from the two lines of code is in fact correct, whether the functions in question are members of the form or not. :-)